# How to imitate "To" button in Outlook application to generate Select Names dialog to retrieve email addresses to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to imitate the Outlook To button for retrieving the Global Address list in an Excel file:
[image: This's my Outlook Appliation.]

[image: I need to imitate this buttons to my excel worksheets.]

My Excel form:
[image: This's my Excel for.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you having problems displaying the address book dialog? Use the `SelectNamesDialog` object: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.selectnamesdialog

Comment: Thank you so much.><